# Doubt about backshift (reported speech) for events that are still on going

Tags: reported-speech, backshifting

I have a doubt about using backshift in this following situation:

Peter: "I have a good job now."

Peter said that he had a good job now.............or................Peter said that he has a good job now.

I appreciate that a similar phrase without the addition of 'now' would be changed to had:  "Peter said that he had a good job", but surely the inclusion of 'now' demands that has should remain in the present and not get backshifted.  It just seems to make more sense like this
Thanks for any advice or comments

Comment: Backshifting is still correct, but you're doing pure reported speech have to backshift the time reference as well.  Replace "now" with "when I spoke with him" or "yesterday" or something like that. You'd use the present tense if you're describing Peter's ongoing attitude towards his job rather than reporting on speech in the past.